# parse.com swift return values from class after query

Tags: swift, search, parse-platform, label

I have a second class in parse where each row is linked to the user and stores an int number. This is already setup.

Now I want to check for the current user and get the int that is saved and put that in a label. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to query with constraints ("meaning that get data only for the currentUser"). Then you have two options to retrieve their data either use `getfirstobjectinbackgroundwithblock() method` which will get at least one row of data from parse. Or use `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock() method` which will return multiple rows from parse.

> if in parse, the user is being saved as pointer use that line:
>
> ```
>  let userT = PFUser.CurrentUser()   //<-- to get CurrentUser
> ```
>
> if in parse, the user is being saved as string use that line
>
> ```
> let userT = PFUser.CurrentUser().username   //<-- to get CurrentUser
> ```

In this code, I use the `getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock` method because I think you are only displaying one thing for the user, So if I am wrong use the second method `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`

```
let query = PFQuery(className:"whateverNameYourClassIs")
let userT = PFUser.CurrentUser()   //<-- to get CurrentUser 
query.whereKey("NameOfUserColummInParse" equalTo:userT!)
query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock { (object: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in 

    if error == nil 
    {
       if let retreiveObject = object
         {
            let data = retreiveObject["IntValue"] as! Int  //<-- IntValue supposed to be the name of your class column in parse where you want to retrieve the value.
         }

    }
})
```

Comment: Great. How can I then set the Label to data? `self.labelName.text = data`  does not work because it is an Int... I need to keep it an Int in parse because I am taking it and then adding something to it as well.

Comment: Try that `self.labelName.text =  "\(data)"`